# Reactjs change state in App.js from external function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

in my `App.js` I have a state for a variable this:

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        httpStatus: false
        }

    // react crap code below

    render() {
        return (
        // blah blah blah blah components
        );
    }
}
```

Then, in a sub folder directory within `src`, I have a folder path `fetch>updateHttp` with a javascript file called `updatehttp.js` that simply has a function (its just a function, not a class or component) that needs to edit/update the state of that `httpStatus` variable:

**updatehttp.js**

```
updateHttp = () => {
    this.setState({
    httpStatus: true
})

export default updateHttp;
```

Is there an easy way to grab the state from the parent class (`App.js`) in this class and simply update it from the external function? I keep getting an error in the function for `no-undef` and I'm pretty certain its because the `this.setState...` call in the `updateHttp` function is not doing anything since it cannot grab the state object that is present in `App.js`.

I'm mostly familiar with Backend Java, so I'm new to React.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to update the state inside the class itself?

Comment: Yes, because I am making an HTTP async FETCH call in the "updateHttp" method (just didnt include all that because I didn't want to make my question convoluted. When the Fetch call is made, I want to render different thing depending on whether its a 200 or like 404 response. I had this in my App.js initially , but my code looked way too messy having so many functions in the App.js @sanmcp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a production code, I would recommend keeping business/infrastructure logic off of the App.js.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import GetResponseCode from "./GetResponseCode";

const App = () => {
  return (
      <>  
        <GetResponseCode/>
      </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

GetResponseCode.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import getDataFromAPI from './getDataFromAPI';

const GetResponseCode = () => {
    const [responseCode, setResponseCode] = useState("") 

    const requestData = () => {
        setResponseCode(getDataFromAPI());
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Response code: {responseCode} </h3>
            <button onClick={requestData}>Get Data</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default GetResponseCode;
```

getDataFromApi.js

```
const getDataFromAPI = () => {
    //call the Api
    //lines below just randomly simulate response code from Api
    const httpCodes = ["200","400","404","500"];
    return httpCodes[Math.floor(Math.random()*httpCodes.length)];
}

export default getDataFromAPI;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to just merge that function into your current App Component?  That would seem the right thing to do here.   See the mock code below for an example of how to do that.

---

```
class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            httpStatus: false
        }

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.updateHttp = this.updateHttp.bind(this);

      }

      handleClick(e) {
        if (someCondition == true) {
            this.updateHttp();
        }
      }

      updateHttp() {
        this.setState({
          httpStatus: true
        });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <SomeComponent onClick={this.handleClick} />
        );
      }
}
```

Comment: well, the "updateHttp' method basically just uses the JS Fetch API to make a POST request on an endpoint. I have a state variable to for the 'httpStatus" to capture whether it returns a 200 or 400 or whatever.